# get option values from database codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a php form where I want to select options for a field Email from a list of values saved in a table emailaddress in the database. The table emailaddress has 2 fields 1. idemailaddress and 2. emailaddress, but I am still getting error trying to pull data, please help

Agreement_ctrl

```
$data['department_list'] = $this->Main_model->get_department_list();
    $data['unit_list'] = $this->Main_model->get_unit_list();
    $data['terms'] = $this->Main_model->get_terms_list();
    $data['emailaddress_list'] = $this->Main_model->get_emailaddress_list();
    $data['managers_list'] = $this->Main_model->get_managers_list();
    $data['mtnlocation_list'] = $this->Main_model->get_mtnlocation_list();
    $data['institution_list'] = $this->Main_model->get_institution_list();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'alpha|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('department', 'Department');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('unit', 'Unit', 'numeric|xss_clean');
```

Main Model File

}

```
function get_emailaddress_list()
{
    $this->db->order_by('emailaddress', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('emailaddress');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $result [$row->id] =  $row;
        }
        return $result;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Form Page

```
                      <div class="form-group row">
             <label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="Email">Email Address:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <select name="Email" class="Email form-control" id="Email">
                                                <option value="" <?php echo  set_select('Email', ''); ?> >-Select-</option>
                                                <?php if($emailaddress_list){ 
                                                    foreach($emailadress_list as $emailaddress){ ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $emailadress->idemailaddress?>" <?php echo set_select('Email', $emailaddress->idemailaddress); ?>><?php echo $emailaddress->emailaddress?></option>
                                                <?php }
                                                    }?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the foreach loop in your model, just return the query result.

```
function get_emailaddress_list(){
  $this->db->order_by('emailaddress', 'ASC');
  $query = $this->db->get('emailaddress');
  $data = ($query->num_rows())? $query->result():false;
  return $data;
}
```

Then you loop through this results in your view to create the select options:

```
<select name="Email" class="Email form-control" id="Email">

  <?php if($emailaddress_list):?> 
      <option value="" disabled selected>-Select-</option>
    <?php foreach($emailadress_list as $row): ?>                                                    
      <option value="<?=$row->idemailaddress?>">
        <?=$row->emailaddress?>
      </option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
  <?php else:?>
     no records found
  <?php endif;?>                                 
</select>
```

Comment: Hello Vickel, thanks for the response, the error from loading the page has stopped, the page is loading but the form field tu populate emailaddress is empty, please help confirm if there is an error in my form view page

Comment: <div class="form-group row"><label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="Email">Email Address:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9"><select name="Email" class="Email form-control" id="Email">
                               <option value="" <?php echo  set_select('Email', ''); ?> >-Select-</option>

Comment: please check what is the output of print_r( $emailaddress_list) ?

Comment: @user2943301: please delete your last comment, if these are real email addresses, thanks, updated answer

Comment: the email didnt populate, even after editing it with the code you gave, what do you think might be wrong

Comment: strange, i just checked it with a db of mine and it works fine, try it without any other html around it and make sure the query returns results (but that should be OK, as by your other deleted comment)

Comment: Hello Vickel, it works now, i saw a div error in my model file. thanks